# Find Duplicate Records in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTable pulgin and had question about adding duplicate row.

When user add a record to (HTML) table I want to check if that record already exists in Table (on client side).

For example:

```
       Column A
Row 1  ABC
```

Now if user try to add "ABC", I want to throw error.

Can anyone provide pointer how to achieve this using jQuery or Datatables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findInTable(str, tableID){
    $('#' + tableID + ' tr').each(function(){
        $(this).children('td').each(function(){
            if ( $(this).html() == str ){
                alert('found');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }); 
}

findInTable('ABC', 'mytable'); // <table id="mytable">...</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. Tweak this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function cellContent() {
  var content=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(c=0;c<content.length;c++) {
   alert ('td cell number '+(c+1)+' contains...\n ' +content[c].innerHTML);
  }
 }
onload=cellContent;
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hacky way to do this for smaller tables. Convert the rows into strings, and put them in an associative array, works best for single column tables, and there are ways to work with multiple columns

Hence lets say you insert ABC

```
if (tableData["ABC"] != undefined) tableData["ABC"] = 1;
else alert("Duplicate");
```

Also if loop should take care of adding the row to the UI